# How to prevent click event over the whole span with children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to prevent triggering the calendar, not only by clicking on the icon but on the whole tag? In this case if I'm trying to do this directly without children selector it's doesn't working.

[My implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/drZPC/)

HTML:

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
    <input type="text" disabled="true"></input> 
    <span class="add-on disabled">
      <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  $(function () {
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

      $(".disabled").children().bind('click', function () {
          return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : http://jsfiddle.net/vg4xa/1/

You have to set your event handler before datepicker init, and stop event propagation :

```
$(function () {
    $('.disabled').bind('click', function(e){
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Even simpler: `$(".disabled i").bind('click', false);`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this solution and still are the same results.

Comment: Don't forget to remove `.children()`

Comment: Behaviour is the same like earlier, calendar is opened when span is clicked.

Comment: could one not also `preventDefault()`?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this answer will not work for the subject, but in the issue description, there is a datepicker and next code works for me to prevent datepicker opening on span or calendar icon click

```
    if (disable) {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('_detachEvents');
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('_detachSecondaryEvents');
    } else {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('_attachEvents');
        $('#datetimepicker1').datepicker('_attachSecondaryEvents');
    }
```